# Deploy MEAN+Webpack on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, webpack, mean

How do I deploy a MEAN STACK+WEBPAC application?

- I have a MEAN Stack  + Webpac application and nodejs server which 
  provides the rest api
- I run the angular application using webpack dev server
- after building the webpack application,I have the build.js file.

How do I reference the build file from the nodejs application? Normally,with requirejs, I would use the html script tag,
this way

```
<script src="build.js" />
```

I understand this is not the webpac way,

Comment: Any update for now?

Comment: I don't know why people downvote this as this is not common knowledge. One would normally think, that what you provide in the package.json is enough, but it turns out, that you actually have to edit batch files on the server. Not developer friendly at all, so +1 for the question.

Answer (score 9):

Generally speaking, we can leverage [Custom Deployment Script](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) to install the nodejs modules and run custom scripts during the Azure Deployment task, to build your webpack application on Azure Web Apps.

Please try the following steps:

1. Create a file `.deployment` and `deploy.cmd` by `azure-cli` command `azure site deploymentscript --node --sitePath nodejs`
2. Run npm command `npm install --save webapck` to install `webpack` into your local application's directory.
3. define a custom npm script in `package.json` file to run `webpack` command and let the deployment task call later:

   `"scripts": {
       "webpack":"node_modules/.bin/webpack"
   },`
4. Modify the `deply.cmd` file, add a process to run the npm script we defined. In the original file, you can find the similar script to install the node.js modules:

   `:: 3. Install npm packages
   IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\package.json" (
   pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"
   call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install --production
   IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
   popd
   )`

   we can define the custom script under it:

   `:: 4. webpack
   IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\webpack.config.js" (
   pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"
   call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! run webpack
   IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
   popd
   )`
5. deploy your webpack application to Azure Web App via Git.

Here is my test [webpack app repository](https://github.com/Walk4Muscle/webpackapp) on Github, FYI.

Comment: hi gary, thanks for the answer, however, one more thing is that my application has a nodejs express backend. how do i run them both when deployed? thanks

Comment: Deploy an express on Azure do not need to configure the deployment script. You can rename the entrance file to `server.js` and `app.js`, change the listen port to `process.env.port`, and use Git to deploy to Azure normally.  You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started/ for more info.

Comment: I got an error like "site is not an azure command". To overcome this, first enter the following command: `azure config mode asm` . After that, `azure site` commands are recognized.

Comment: For some reason, even though webpack is installed, there's no "node_modules/.bin/webpack" available so the build fails for me. Any ideas?

Comment: My webpack unpacks my back-end bundle to a dist folder, I need to run node from there. Any idea how this can be accomplished?

Comment: You can append the steps in `deploy.cmd` file like the 4th point in my answer. Try the command `call :ExecuteCmd node dist/<script>`