# Microsoft Azure hosting | Nodejs | file doesn't get compiled by webpack

Tags: node.js, azure, webpack

I'm trying to build a webapp using nodejs. It compiles and runs fine on my local machine but when I try to host it on Azure, webpack seems to cause problem.

```
//webpack.config.js

var config = {
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
      path:'/',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },

   devServer: {
      // inline: true,
      // port: 8080
   },

   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

module.exports = config;
```

This is the file hierarchy:

[image: File hierarchy]

This is the sources tab in Chrome Dev tool for local machine. I notice here the index.js get compiled as specified in the config file.

[image: Local source]
[image]

Then I just place the source on the server using git. This is the response I get from the server:

[image]

This is the sources tab for the hosting server.

[image: remote source]
[image]

I suspect that it could be because there is difference in interpreting the directories on my local machine and the host?! I'm using MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you would need to compile your WebPack application first before deploying to Azure production server. However, you can also leverage [Custom Deployment Script](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38417491924/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart1/#.WK_G7_l96Uk) to install Node.js modules and run custom scripts to build your WebPack application on Azure Web Apps during the Azure Deployment task. For detailed steps, please check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698418/deploy-meanwebpack-on-azure/38711819#38711819) on StackOverflow.

Comment: I followed the post but and installed Azure CLI. Then there is a following error message

remote: KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository\nodejs' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
remote: Error: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\home\site\repository\nodejs'.
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
remote: Kudu Sync failed
remote: 
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed.

Plus, do I expect a deploy.sh or deploy.exe? I use MacOS, so it would make sense on my computer, how about on Azure?

Comment: Please see my [earlier post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960685/azure-fails-when-i-try-to-deploy-through-github/40988649#40988649).

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I'm very close now. :: 4. webpack
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\webpack.config.js" (
pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"
call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! run webpack
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
popd
)

. I'm just wondering if there is a tool to convert this into .sh script?