# How to deploy socket.io and React app to Azure?

Tags: node.js, sockets, azure, reactjs, socket.io

I'm a total newbie to web development, so please guide me.

I've successfully finished a socket.io and reactjs website locally using tools like webpack and babel. There's one Nodejs server file(also has socket.io) and remaining all are client-side files.

I want to deploy this app to Azure using Azure App Services.
 How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try going through [Create a Node.js chat application with Socket.IO in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-nodejs-chat-app-socketio). For webpack application, you can check out [my earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428437/microsoft-azure-hosting-nodejs-file-doesnt-get-compiled-by-webpack/42431547#42431547) on SO.